# Making the button pop up when pressing the button for a long time in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, uibutton

I would like to make my button pop up when i actually press the button for more than one secs. When it pops up, the letter or word in the button should appear with it... Any guidance on how to do this? Would really appreciate any help provided...

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, What you need to do is implemenent longtap on that Button. `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. So what that gesture takes over, you can animate the `CGSizeMake` to make the frame grow bigger than what it is or you could use `scale` property to scale the button bigger.

Hope this is clear enough. Let me know if this works out for you...

**UPDATE:** Some code -

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIButton *btn;
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        btn = (UIButton *)gesture.view;
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y, 150, 70)];
    }
    return;
}
```

FYI, LongTap gesture has different states `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`. There are some more but these are the main.

Comment: I will attempt myself on this. and post the code in the question. will keep u updated...

Comment: again, at this line: btn.frame.size = CGSizeMake(150,70);
it says not assignable.

Comment: duh! I think `CGMakeSize` might not work here as it might be RO. Try `CGFrameSize`. I have changed the code above too.

Comment: when i do what you said, the app blacks out a bit and the rest of the button are unclickable...